# Buildozer can't load CSV module after removing it from blacklist

Tags: android, python, csv, pip, buildozer

I am building app for android using python, kivy and Buildozer. I am including CSV module in code.
CSV module is blacklisted by default in Buildozer in *blacklist.txt*

I removed it from all *blacklist.txt* files. 
After that if I try "buildozer android debug" this error occurs:

```
# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/tibor/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/tibor/projects/wisdoms_deploy/.buildozer/applibs csv
```

In detailed log from buildozer pip is this:

```
Downloading/unpacking csv
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/csv/
URLs to search for versions for csv:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/csv/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/csv/
Skipping link http://www.object-craft.com.au/projects/csv/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/csv/); not a file
```

It indicates that it wants to download csv from wrong page as on that pages is nothing.

I am stuck at this point and can't figure out, how to add csv module to buildozer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've added then csv module to the requirements line so buildozer is trying to install it. This is not necessary as it is a built in module, just remove it.

Also, probably a better way to unblacklist it would be to add it in the whitelist option. This removes the need to manually edit the blacklist files.

Comment: Yes you were right I had csv included in buildozer.spec as requirement. After I removed it, application runs ok. Thank you.